# A question about Yitang Zhang's paper "On the zeros of ζ’(s) near the critical line"

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

> We conclude that, in the case $\sigma = 1/2$ and $\zeta’\left(s\right) \neq 0$,
>
> $$\mathrm{Re}\frac{\eta’}{\eta}\left(s\right) = \sum_{\beta’ \gt 0}{\mathrm{Re}\frac{1}{s - \rho’}} + O(1)$$
>
> It is easy to see that, for $s = 1/2 + it$, the error term in (2.9) is continuous in $t$. If $\eta(1/2 + it) \neq 0$, then
>
> $$-\sum_{\beta’ \gt 0}{\mathrm{Re}\frac{1}{1/2 + it - \rho’}} = F_{1}(t) - F_{2}(t)$$
>
> where
>
> $$F_{1}(t) = -\sum_{\beta’ \gt 1/2}{\mathrm{Re}\frac{1}{1/2 + it - \rho’}}$$
> $$F_{2}(t) = -\sum_{0 \lt \beta’ \lt 1/2}{\mathrm{Re}\frac{1}{1/2 + it - \rho’}}$$

I am wondering where the terms with $\beta’=1/2$ are.

Comment: for $\beta'=1/2$ the term $1/2-\rho'$ is purely imaginary so there is no contribution to the sum over real parts.

Answer (score 5):

As Carlo Beenakker mentions in the comments,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\sum_{\beta'=1/2} \mathrm{Re} \left(\frac{1}{1/2+it-\rho'}\right)&=- \mathrm{Re}\left( \frac{1}{1/2+it-(1/2+it')}\right)\\
&=- \mathrm{Re}\left( \frac{1}{(t-t')i}\right)=0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

I suggest that you run this type of question by [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) first.